# Using UI Sortable, move item to new location based on a given value when I click a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, onclick, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there a way to force the UI Sortable to change item position in a list when I click some link or a button that pass a value to any of the possible UI events?

**Here the Sortable function:**

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
       // ... 
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
       // ... 
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
       // ... 
    }
});
```

And here is the even of a button which update the value of a text input in spicific row ... It actually fires an Ajax but I'm making it simple here:

```
$("#sortable tr").on("click", ".row-button", function () {
    var sort_id = $this.closest('tr').find('.text-sort-id').val();
    ...
    ...
});
```

## UPDATE:

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mxn8ptL/embedded/#Result) result of what I did till now. I need to be able when I change the input in second row for example to "5" and click change it visually move to the bottom of the table and so on when change the fourth row input to "1".

**I want to be able to change item value when click the change button without resetting all others and from another side, be able to drag any row and change its input value to be less than the one after and more then the input before it and this all happens without changing other values even if we needed to set an equal value.**

Comment: Would you be able to create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) of what you have done so far?

Comment: Thanks @Yass I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the comments in the code for an explanation of what I'm doing. I've updated the `.sort-btn` `click` event with the following code:

```
$(".grid-sort-table tbody tr").on("click", ".sort-btn", function() {
    var allItems = $('.ui-sortable').children();

    //Select all of the input values
    var orderedInputValues = $.map(allItems, function(item) {
            return $(item).find('input').val();
    });

    //Order the input values (smallest to largest, by default)
    orderedInputValues = orderedInputValues.sort(); 

    //Store the "tr" in a variable so it can be manipulated.
    var selectedItem = $(this).closest('tr');
    var selectedItemVal = $(selectedItem).find('input').val();

    var indexToInsertAt = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < orderedInputValues.length; i++) {
        if (orderedInputValues[i] == selectedItemVal) {
        indexToInsertAt = i;
        break;
      }
    }

    //Find the item at the index the selected item will be inserted at (before or after)
    var itemAtIndex = allItems[indexToInsertAt];

    //If the selected item's value is greater than the item at the required index, insert it after the item.
    if ($(selectedItem).find('input').val() > $(itemAtIndex).find('input').val()) {
        selectedItem.insertAfter(itemAtIndex);
    }
    else { //Otherwise, insert it before the item at the required index.
        selectedItem.insertBefore(itemAtIndex);
    }
    //Additional code below
    ...
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/1mxn8ptL/9/)**

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Yass, It's working but with a few issues. for example try to give the third row value of "7" or even "4" it won't go down but it's working if "2". Good job

Comment: Oh .. I just noticed that the Sortable update event that i just tested before posting gives values to all and changes all items values accordingly. I will not need this to happen in some cases. here is an updated Fuddle using your click event where I still need your help to not change other rows values . https://jsfiddle.net/1mxn8ptL/4/

Comment: Fine let me summary all my final needs, I want to be able to change item value when click the change button without resetting all others and from another side, be able to drag any row and change its input value to be less than the one after and more then the input before it and this all happens without changing other values even if we needed to set an equal value.

Comment: Look at the comments in the code and you should be able to change enough to prevent the values in the textboxes from upating. I don't have time to look at this at the moment and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm really thankful @Yass for getting back to it ...I was trying on another one to get the position based one before and after input value not itemindex (i tried jquery  filter selector ) . You still doing this with itemindex, hence if you tried to change the value of "7" to "4" it still goes to the last row I also wish (and this is an option) to fill the input of the dragged row with the a greater or a lower value of the one before or after ... try this https://jsfiddle.net/1mxn8ptL/7/ . If you didn't find out how or couldn't understand my lang. I can mark it an answer since it really helped.

Comment: I'm trying : var targetIndex = $('.ui-sortable .td-sort-id').filter(function () { return $(this).attr("value") > itemIndex; }).closest('tr').index();

Comment: I believe I did answer your original question to a satisfactory standard, but if you're not happy with the answer you don't have to mark it as such. I can still look into this further, but you have to understand my time is limited on weekdays.

Comment: I'm happy in all cases and have no problem with marking it .. you were nice enough actually .. BTW, I was commenting last time to say so and then gave it one more try  and I still saving the long thank text in a notepad :)

Comment: Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/1mxn8ptL/9/). It's no longer using the index and instead is checking the values in the text boxes.

Comment: GREAT ... I have also updated the after drag (stop) function to fill the value of dragged row with the next value (prev + 1) https://jsfiddle.net/1mxn8ptL/10/ ... Please have a look if you have any notes and if not and you would like to update your answer with the final result please do. I consider it done and more over you really didn't waste your time because that will add a lot to my work. THANKS :)

Comment: OOOPS .. try changing value to more than 10 ... 13 for example ...  Done here https://jsfiddle.net/1mxn8ptL/12/